# Dojo widget for displaying connection status

Tags: dojo, widget

in my dojo web app, I would like to display the connection status through a red / green light, possibly circular like a traffic light.
Is there anybody who knows an existing widget for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such widget existing yet. You can create your own widget. It's not a hard task to do that. Just use two different images to represent the state.